# Docker error Getaddrinfo: Name or service not known in Puma Nginx server-Mac os

Tags: ruby-on-rails, docker, nginx, docker-compose

I am getting the following error while running `docker run myapp`:

> ```
> ! Unable to load application: SocketError: getaddrinfo: Name or service not 
>      known
>      bundler: failed to load command: puma (/usr/local/bundle/bin/puma)
> ```

Below are my configurations and Dockerfiles:

**DockerFile in App**

```
FROM ruby:2.5.0
# Set an environment variable where the Rails app is installed to inside of Docker image
ENV RAILS_ROOT /Users/admin/git/generic/myapp
ENV REDIS_URL=redis://redis:6379/0
RUN mkdir -p $RAILS_ROOT 
# Set working directory
WORKDIR $RAILS_ROOT
# Setting env up
ENV RAILS_ENV='production'
ENV RACK_ENV='production'
# Adding gems
#COPY ./Users/admin/git/generic/myapp/Gemfile ./Users/admin/git/generic/myapp/app/docker/app/Gemfile
#COPY ./Users/admin/git/generic/myapp/Gemfile.lock ./Users/admin/git/generic/myapp/app/docker/web/Gemfile.lock

COPY Gemfile Gemfile
COPY Gemfile.lock Gemfile.lock

RUN bundle install
# Adding project files
COPY . .
RUN gem install bundler
RUN bundle install
COPY . .
EXPOSE 3000
CMD ["bundle", "exec", "puma", "-C", "config/puma.rb","production"]
```

**DockerFile in Web**

```
FROM nginx
# Install dependencies
RUN apt-get update -qq && apt-get -y install apache2-utils
# establish where Nginx should look for files
ENV RAILS_ROOT /Users/admin/git/generic/myapp
# Set our working directory inside the image
WORKDIR $RAILS_ROOT
# create log directory
RUN mkdir log
# copy over static assets
COPY public public/
# Copy Nginx config template
COPY docker/web/nginx.conf /tmp/docker.nginx
# put the final config in its place
RUN envsubst '$RAILS_ROOT' < /tmp/docker.nginx > /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
EXPOSE 80
# Use the "exec" form of CMD so Nginx shuts down gracefully on SIGTERM (i.e.  `docker stop`)
CMD [ "nginx", "-g", "daemon off;" ]
```

**My Nginx config**

```
 upstream docker { 
     server 127.0.0.1:3000; 
 }

 server {  
     # define your domain  
     # define the public application root  
     listen 80;
     root   $RAILS_ROOT/public;  
     index  index.html;
     # define where Nginx should write its logs  
     access_log $RAILS_ROOT/log/nginx.access.log;  
     error_log $RAILS_ROOT/log/nginx.error.log;   


      # send non-static file requests to the app server  
      location / { 
          proxy_pass http://docker; 
      } 
}
```

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: '3'
volumes:  
  postgres_data: {} 

services:
  redis:
    image: redis
    command: redis-server
    ports:
      - "6379:6379"
  app:    
    build:      
      context: .      
      dockerfile: /Users/admin/git/generic/myapp/docker/app/DockerFile 
    depends_on:      
      - db  
  db:    
    image: postgres    
    volumes:      
      - postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data  
  web:    
    build:      
      context: .      
      dockerfile: /Users/admin/git/generic/myapp/docker/web/DockerFile  
    depends_on:      
      - app    
    ports:      
      - 80:80
```

Puma.rb

```
workers Integer(ENV['WEB_CONCURRENCY'] || 2)
threads_count = Integer(ENV['MAX_THREADS'] || 5)
 threads threads_count, threads_count

preload_app!

rackup      DefaultRackup
port        ENV['PORT']     || 3000
environment ENV['RACK_ENV'] || 'production'

on_worker_boot do
ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection
end
```

Can anyone help how to fix this Socket error.Local host already added in my host file.I have tried changes in nginx config also. Still i am facing same issue.

Comment: can you add the content of config/puma.rb?

Comment: I have added  puma.rb config also

Comment: I have tried to check ip of docker machine using docker-machine env myapp but i am getting Docker machine "myapp" does not exist.

Comment: Now i am getting postgres error while running localhost:3000

Comment: could not connect to server: Connection refused Is the server running on host "localhost" (127.0.0.1) and accepting TCP/IP connections on port 5432? could not connect to server: Cannot assign requested address Is the server running on host "localhost" (::1) and accepting TCP/IP connections on port 5432?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a docker compose context, each container has it's own IP address. You can address those containers by using the docker compose service name as if it was their host name.

You nginx config should then be:

```
upstream docker { 
     server app:3000; 
}
```

Since the `app` and `web` containers have different IP addresses, you also need to make sure the `app` container process is binding to **`0.0.0.0`**`:3000`. I am not familiar with rails or puma, but it seems you can do this with `CMD ["bundle", "exec", "puma", "-C", "config/puma.rb", "production", "-b", "tcp://0.0.0.0:3000"]` in your `app` Dockerfile.

Comment: ok thanks.I made changes.I am running docker-compose build again.

Comment: still i am facing issue.

Comment: docker-compose up has started puma without any issue.But docker run myapp getting this error

Comment: ! Unable to load application: SocketError: getaddrinfo: Name or service not 
         known
         bundler: failed to load command: puma (/usr/local/bundle/bin/puma)

Comment: What is the difference between docker compose up and docker run?

Comment: with docker-compose, a virtual network is created and all containers from your docker-compose.yml file join that network. You can address those containers by the service name found in the docker-compose.yml file

Comment: @user1984 also make sure puma is binding to `0.0.0.0` or the open port would only reachable from the app container

Comment: ok thanks.As you suggested, i have made changes ["bundle", "exec", "puma", "-C", "config/puma.rb", "production", "-b", "tcp://0.0.0.0:3000"]. Still i am facing same issue.